# How to return the most frequent value for a range of unique ID's returned by a select statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, merge, count

I have a series of select statements that returns a list of unique ID's based on several where clauses in a Group By Query into an Output table.

What I also want to be able to select  is the most frequent TeamName value from the table where the ID exists in the output table.

i.e. The output table shows

```
DocTypeID       |     No Source   |  No Date     |     No RefNo     |    TeamName
--------------- |---------------- |------------- |------------------| -------------
926c4185        |        2        |   1          |     69           |       NULL
bff5be99        |        3        |   3          |     5368         |       NULL    
a04d4rf         |        NULL     |   NULL       |     26           |       NULL
```

The TeamName value exists in TableA along with the DocTypeID but there can be different TeamName values for the same Doctype ID hence why i need to pull out the most frequent value (that is not NULL).

I can ascertain the most frequent value with something like this -

```
select top 1 [TeamName] , count([TeamName]) 'count' 
from Documents             
where DocTypeID = '926c4185' 
group by [TeamName] 
order by count desc
```

But am struggling when trying to update the output table with the TeamName value. I have unsuccessfully tried merging the tables but not sure if this is even the right way to go about it.

Apologies for the vagueness, a point in the right direction would be much appreciated. More detail can be provided if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use a correlated subquery or `apply`:

```
select ot.*, d.TeamName
from outputtable ot outer apply
     (select top 1 d.TeamName, count(*) as cnt 
      from Documents d           
      where d.DocTypeID = ot.DocTypeId
      group by d.TeamName
      order by cnt desc
     ) d;
```

Note:  If multiple teams appears equally frequently, then one is arbitrarily chosen.